# Angular override HttpErrorReponse object properties

Tags: node.js, angular, response, http-error

I am fairly new to Angular (8), but have been building a front-end SPA which makes http calls using the HttpClient module to a Node Express back-end API. In the API response I am able to set an Http response status along with an additional JSON object using the below as a basic example:

```
router.delete('/api/admin/roles', auth, (req, res) => {
  queries.deleteRole(req.query.roleid, (err,result) => {
    if (err) {
      if (err.number == 547) {
        return res.status(409).json({
          message: 'Users exist with this role. Cannot cascade delete.'
        })
      }
      return res.status(500).send()
    }
    return res.send(result)
  })
})
```

When i run the above in a development environment, I can successfully intercept the HttpErrorResponse and access the err.error object with the message property. My interceptor looks like this:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError((err: any) => {
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          if (err.status === 401) {
            this.toastService.show(new Toast('Your session has expired and you have been logged out. Please log back in.', 'Session expired', {'delay': 5000, 'classname': 'bg-info text-light'}))
            this.authService.logOut();
          } else if (err.status === 409) {
            console.log(err)
            let errText = err.error.message || 'Record has been updated by another user. Please refresh page and retry.'
            this.toastService.show(new Toast(errText
            , 'Update conflict', {'delay': 5000, 'classname': 'bg-danger text-light'}))
          } else if (err.status == 403) {
            this.toastService.show(new Toast('You do not have the appropriate permissions to perform this action. Please contact your line manager to request access.'
            , 'Not authorized', {'delay': 5000, 'classname': 'bg-danger text-light'}))
          }
        }

        return next.handle(req)
      })
    )
  }
```

This all works fine in development.
However, when I run `ng build --prod` and deploy my application to an IIS server (using iisnode), and create the same conditions to receive an HttpError from the API, my response error property no longer contains my custom object, but instead reverts to "The page was not displayed because there was a conflict.", which I'm guessing is some standard string given the 409 response?

I can't see why in either my Angular code or Node this should behave differently dependent on the environment, so I'm assuming this has something to do with the `ng build --prod` command - or alternatively the iisnode deployment. Google has not been helpful and in fact on every message board or tutorial I've come across, the suggested solution seems to broadly match what I am doing, with no indication that there might be any difference when deploying to Production or any mention from anyone else that they encounter the same issue.

SO, is there something obvious or not so obvious I'm missing? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I ended up figuring this out and a quick Google including the term "iisnode" immediately provided a solution. How I didn't think of this before, I'm not sure.

Anyway, for anyone else struggling with this, this is the link I followed for a resolution:
https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/295

Basically you need to add two things to the web.config file on iisnode:

```
  <configuration>
    <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="off" />    <-- this one here
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />    <-- and this one too
...
```

The thread actually says to use `<httpErrors existingResponse="passthrough" />` but I found that using "PassThrough"  (with capitalization) worked where the original lowercase value did not.